# Expanding user path with boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

Is there functionality in `boost::filesystem` to expand paths that begin with a user home directory symbol (`~` on Unix), similar to the [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) function provided in Python?

Comment: Have you tried to use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical ?

Comment: @Hamdor I did try something like `canonical(path("~/test.txt"))`, but that didn't work. Incorrect usage?

Comment: I doubt there is. But see also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891006/how-to-create-a-folder-in-the-home-directory

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

But you can implement it by doing something like this:

```
  namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;
  using std;

  bfs::path expand (bfs::path in) {
    if (in.size () < 1) return in;

    const char * home = getenv ("HOME");
    if (home == NULL) {
      cerr << "error: HOME variable not set." << endl;
      throw std::invalid_argument ("error: HOME environment variable not set.");
    }

    string s = in.c_str ();
    if (s[0] == '~') {
      s = string(home) + s.substr (1, s.size () - 1);
      return bfs::path (s);
    } else {
      return in;
    }
  }
```

Also, have a look at the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891006/how-to-create-a-folder-in-the-home-directory) suggested by @WhiteViking.

Comment: Note that this isn't cross-platform or guaranteed to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3733955/6296561

Comment: This is actually downright wrong. For example, if you're logged in as user "admin", it will expand "~celmin/some/path" to "/home/admin/celmin/some/path" instead of the correct "/home/celmin/some/path". Even if you don't want to handle expanding another user's directory you should probably at least check that the second character is /. (Also as mentioned this only works on POSIX platforms.)